# Base, thumbnail and small images are not creating under pub/media/catalog in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, thumbnails

I have added a product from magento admin and uploaded image for that product. Images are showing in backend but not showing in frontend.

I found that the image cache folder for thumbnail,base and small is not created under pub/media folder.So that images are not showing.

I have tried all the magento possible command to fix this but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the permission on the folder? The current php user has to have the right to write inside the folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).